# reuse serialized reference to "this"-Keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, serialization, reference, this

First things first: I'm not sure whether the information that I'm going to provide will be enough, I will happily add additional information if needed.

I'm serializing a complex structure into the JSON-Format, Field[i][0] is the "this"-reference to an object.

Firebug's Output on JSON.Stringify(myObj)

[image: Firebug Printscreen]

This is all fine and working as long as I keep it all JS. But now I have the requirement to serialize and send it to my backend to get the reference + computed information back.

Now how do I map back to the reference I had before? How do I bind this ref back to an Object?
This $$hash thing looks internal and proprietarish so I havent even bothered trying something like Object[$$hash] = ref or whatever.

This general idea probably seems pretty whack, but the result is returned asynchrously and I need an identifier to bind the new information back to the original object. Obviously I could just make up my own identifier for that, but I was wondering whether there's an option to solve it this way.

**EDIT**

The objects are created like this (likewise)

```
var arrayOfObj = []

arrayOfObj.push(new Object.With.SomeSettersAndGetters());
```

The Object has a method like

```
function GetRef(){
return this;
}
```

Which I'm using to keep a ID/Ref through my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code how the object is being created?

Comment: Show us the serialisation code and we can help you with the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want to update a series of instances and make many Ajax requests, then you need to look at Ajax long polling and queueing techniques. You won't be able to preserve the reference, but regardless of what Ajax technique you use, make use of the below trick to preserve the reference.

Add long polling on top and you're good to go.

The idea is this:

Assume the server will respond in JSON format. If you need to refer to the original references, here's my two cents:

Update the exact references when the server replies. Say you have 10 instances of `Something` stored in an array. On a successful response, you use the methods in the `Something` class to update the specific instances in whatever way you want.

```
  /**
   * The array with something instances.
   * @type {Array.<Something>}
   */
  var instances = [];

  /**
   * The Ajax success function.
   * @param {Event} event The event object.
   */
  function ajaxSuccess(event) {
       var response = event.target.getResponseText();
       var actualResponse = JSON.parse(response);
       for (var i = 0, len = actualResponse.length; i++) {
           instances[i].setWhatever(actualResponse[i].whatever);
       };
    };
```

The above is a more procedural approach. If you want full blown OOP in JS, then you think in modular design patterns. Say you have a module that loads data into some place. Basically, everything related to that module is an instance property.

```
var myModule = function() {
    this.whatever = 1;
};
myModule.prototype.loadMore = function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        that = this; // store a reference to this.
    request.send(); // etc
    request.onreadystatechange = that.onSucess;
};
myModule.prototype.onSucess = function(event) {
    var response = JSON.parse(event.target.getResponseText());
    this.whatever = response.whatever;

};
var moduleInstance = new myModule();
myModule.loadMore();
// Now the scope is always preserved. The callback function will be executed in the right scope.
```

Let's assume on the backend side of things, you have a model class that mimics your client side JavaScript model. Say you want to update a reference inside a model that displays text. I use Scala on the backend, but look at the fields/properties and ignore the syntax.

```
case class Article (
    title: String,// these are my DB fields for an Article.
    punchline: String,
    content: String,
    author: String
);
// now assume the client is making a request and the server returns the JSON
// for an article. So the reply would be something like:
{"title": "Sample title", "punchline": "whatever", "content": "bla bla bla boring", "author": "Charlie Sheen"};
// when you do 
var response = JSON.parse(event.target.getResponseText());
// response will become a JavaScript object with the exact same properties.
// again, my backend choice is irrelevant.

// Now assume I am inside the success function, which gets called in the same scope
// as the original object, so it refers TO THE SAME THING.
// the trick is to maintain the reference with var that = this.
// otherwise the onSuccess function will be called in global scope.
// now because it's pointing to the same object.
// I can update whatever I want.
this.title = response.title;
this.punchline = response.punchline;
this.content = response.content;
this.author = response.author;
// or I can put it all in a single variable.
this.data = response;
```

What you need to remember is that scope needs to be preserved. That's the trick.
When I do `var that = this;` I copy a reference to the model instance. The reference is remembered through higher-order, not current scope.

Then I tell the `XMLHttpRequest` object to call `that.ajaxSuccess` when it is complete. Because I used `that`, the `ajaxSuccess` function will be called in the scope of the current object. So inside the `ajaxSuccess` function, `this` will point to the original `this`, the same instance.

JavaScript remembers it for me it when I write `var that = this;`

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for the response.
I totally see your approach with simple datastructures (e.g. this.whatever = 1;) But my this.whatever is a reference to an JS internal Object. How am I supposed to keep this? Updating with something new would break that reference to the data.

Comment: So JSON.parse is/should be creating the same object reference that was there before, based on the ref information?

Comment: alex, I'm aware of that (I think). Again, I dont want to update the reference, I want the reference *itself* ! As you can see in the printscreen above, I'm getting my reference from the backend back as field $$hash I'd like to reuse this very ref.

Comment: that wont help either, as I have an array of these elements, and for each element I'll be initiating a new RPC Call -> Async -> response should lead back to the original object. :-) Sorry it seems complex.

Comment: updating them at once wouldnt work in my case (some single request can take up to 30 secs). I want the result from the multiple RPCs to come in async. Handling this synchronously/all at once would be way easier, I agree.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know - could you please add a little EDIT or Something on Top so I can accept your answer? I will solve this by creating specific UIDs for each object, pass them with the RPC and use them later for matching - ugly, but I was expecting that. :-)

Comment: unfortunately switching to a long-polling/comit based approach is not easy in my case, as I'm looking for a simple solution to comply with earlier uses of our rpc-abstraction code. Thank you for your patience.